# Near Realtime Indexing and non-deterministic getTermVector results

Tags: lucene

I am trying to use Lucene 4.9 as indexing mechanism that returns documents' Terms in NRT mode. For this purpose I use the following Field configuration:

```
    FieldType t2 = new FieldType();
    t2.setIndexed(true);
    t2.setStored(true);
    t2.setTokenized(true);
    t2.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    t2.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
    t2.setIndexOptions(FieldInfo.IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS);
```

and the following IndexWriterConfig:

```
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(VERSION);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(VERSION, analyzer);
```

My flow is as follows:

```
   indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
   IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, true);
   // ... i = find document id using indexReader
   Terms terms = handler.indexReader.getTermVector(i, CONTENTS_FIELD_NAME);
```

I would expect that after calling *addDocument(doc)* and *IndexReader* will be able to provide me correctly populated TermVector. In my test scenario it works mostly as expected, but there are some situations that TermVector size is smaller than it should be. Results are unreliable and non-deterministic (occurs 5-10 times per 2000 items).

Adding, lets say, 500 ms pause right after *addDocument(doc)* statement - make things working correctly.

My assumption is that field indexing is being done asynchronously, but NRT's IndexReader gives a pointer to somehow 'incomplete' snapshot.

Is there any way to ensure that document has been analysed and ensure that getTermVector() will return correct value?

**UPDATE:**

Adding 500 ms pause AFTER (instead of before) *IndexReader* assignment also helps. So it seems that this issue is only related to delayed/incomplete field analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Commit the index before reading. From the [API reference](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#commit()), commit() command commits all pending changes (added & deleted documents, segment merges, added indexes, etc.) to the index, and syncs all referenced index files, such that a reader will see the changes and the index updates will survive an OS or machine crash or power loss. Note that this does not wait for any running background merges to finish.

Note that this may be a costly operation, so you should test the cost in your application and do it only when really necessary.